# Unable to verify your credentials Twitter Error Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-oauth

Im integrating Twitter in my Ruby on Rails App.

im using gem 'twitter'

and i want to fetch my followers count

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new


@talking_about_count = graph.get_object("iscopeapp")["talking_about_count"]

@followers = client.followers("AnabtaTec")
```

---

The Thing is when i access the page this error apears.

Twitter::Error::Forbidden in HomeController#index

### Unable to verify your credentials

I guess im missing some tokens or something. Could anyone help or guide me to get these tokens and then how to implement them in my controller?

Thanks in Advance guys!

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are missing your credentials.

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

You can get the keys from 
https://dev.twitter.com/ and setting up your app.  If you are pulling in the count for different users, then you would setup something like devise with omniauth and store the key off in the table for each user.

Comment: Do i declare this block in my controller? Thank you!

Comment: çI did everything now...and im getting "could not authenticate you"